# How to use and initialize a variable haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a function in Haskell that given a list, returns some of its permutations.

My problem is that I have to give the length of the list in order for the function to work. Is there any way to change that using `let` or `where`?

```
generate_permutations list 0 = my_permutation 1 4 list
generate_permutations list n = list (my_permutation (list!!n) 4 list) ++ generate_permutations list (n-1)
```

I want to initialize n with length of the list.

1. I don't know how to do it.
2. If I manage to do it how can I stop the recursion?

Comment: The word "initialisation" totally doesn't make sense for a Haskell variable, because if you give a variable a value "initially" that means it'll have this value _forever_. Why would you want to give something a particular value, if not to ensure that value can be used later on without having to worry somebody might have changed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no variable assignment in Haskell. However you could use a `where` clause to assign a name to an expression:

```
generate_permutations list =
    my_permutation (list!!n) 4 list ++ generate_permutations list (n-1)
  where
    n = length list
```

Comment: I don't know what `my_permutation` does, but I took the liberty of removing the `list` name used as a function. I'm pretty sure you meant something else.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to use a `where`:

```
generate_permutations list = go list (length list)
    where
        go xs 0 = my_permutation 1 4 list
        go xs n = list (my_permutation (list!!n) 4 list) ++ go list (n - 1)
        --        ^--- What is this doing here?  This will cause a type error
```

The name `go` is quite popular for functions like this, but you can use whatever you like.  Assuming that `my_permutation` exits, this function will as well.  Your recursion decrements from `n = length list` to `n = 0` in a pretty common pattern.